# SDN pox controller

Tags: python, sdn, pox

To find tcp port on pox controller i have to look for the ports through wireshark,only after starting the controller.is there any method to find tcp port through python program itself on pox controller

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you need the ports of all hosts in the network, the ports involved in a packet coming through? At which point should you obtain this info?